# Batch file to generate 100 folders with 100 subfolders within each folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I'm trying to create a batch script which generates 100 folders (app1, app2, app3...) along with 100 subfolders (data1, data2, data3) in each independent folder. That way, the folder "app1" will contain 100 subfolders named "data1", "data2", "data3"... The same apply to "app2", "app3"... Till now I've only got:

```
    for /L %%g in (1,1,100) do (
    md app%%g\data%%g
)
```

The problem with that is that each of the 100 "data" subfolders are created separatly on each of the "app" folders. That way, the "app1" folder has only one of the "data" subfolders instead of 100. How can I fix this?

Best regards!

Comment: Nested `FOR /L` commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two nested `for /L` loops

```
for /L %%g in (1 1 100) do (
  for /L %%h in (1 1 100) do (
    md app%%g\data%%h
  )
)
```

Be aware this will create 10000 directories on your drive.  It could take a while thrashing your HDD.

Comment: Six seconds on my computer.